# qt gui to display video using Qfiledialogbox and qlabel .here is my code

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, qlabel, qmediaplayer

**FIRST CODE** 
In this code VideoCapture cap is not taking filename (which contains video path) which is obtained after executing QFileDialog i.e. with  cap.open("fileName") ,code is not executing while with cap.open("G:/mixer.avi") ,code is executing . means If video path is directly given in cap.open() then code is executing but it is not taking QFileDialog output i.e. filename as input

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
 if(ui->radioButton->isChecked()) {


      QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,
          tr("Open Video"), "G://", "All files (*.*);Video files(*.*)");
      ui->lineEdit->setText(fileName);
     VideoCapture cap
    // cap.open("G:/mixer.avi");
     cap.open("fileName");

    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(update_window()));
    timer->start(20);}}
    void MainWindow::update_window()
     {
     cap >> frame;

    cvtColor(frame, frame, cv::COLOR_BGR2RGB);

    qt_image = QImage((const unsigned char*) (frame.data), frame.cols, frame.rows, 
     QImage::Format_RGB888);

    ui->label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(qt_image));

    ui->label->resize(ui->label->pixmap()->size());
}
```

**SECOND CODE** :

In this code with QFileDialogbox, video is displaying but it is not displaying in QLabel.How to add QLabel in QMultimedia.

```
 void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
    {
    if(ui->radioButton_2->isChecked()) {

    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,
              tr("Open Video"), "G://", "All files (*.*);Video files(*.*)");
     ui->lineEdit->setText(fileName);
       player = new QMediaPlayer;
            vw=new QVideoWidget;
          player->setVideoOutput(vw) ;
          this->setCentralWidget(vw);
           player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile(fileName));
           vw->show();
          player->play();

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[VideoCapture(const String &    filename)](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#a949d90b766ba42a6a93fe23a67785951) can take string as input not QString. 2 things needed to do:

1. First convert QString filename to string
2. There can be some extra characters in the first places of that string because the filedialog chosen file output little different than which opencv `VideoCapture` need.

Comment: I have converted QString to string using code - std::string videopath = fileName.toLocal8Bit().constData();but code is not running. and What types of extra characters are needed in the first places of that string.because filedialog give the same path as we needed in videocapture.

Comment: Is there any other code to open filedialog using c++ instead of QFiledialog.? so that we can get String instead of QString.

Comment: No, for filedialog you need qt.  First try to show the video with ```imshow``` instead of using qlabel. Check it first the problem of not showing may be on the ui side.

Comment: I have displayed video using imshow successfully  but i have to select the file from the folder which needs open the file dialogbox.if i use filedialogbox using qt then video is not displayed using imshow videocapture cap is not taking the qstring.How to select a file from a folder.